# Flutter build failed with "contacts_service" package, related to android.jar

Tags: flutter, dart

When trying to build a Flutter project, I encountered an error related to the "contacts_service" package. The error message indicates that the build failed during the task "**:contacts_service:parseDebugLocalResources**", with the message "**Could not resolve all files for configuration ':contacts_service:androidApis**'. Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: /Users/meliharik/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar. /Users/meliharik/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar".

I searched on Stack Overflow for similar issues and found a few suggestions. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, as well as running "flutter clean" and "flutter pub cache repair" commands, but none of them solved the issue. I also tried updating the "contacts_service" package to the latest version, but it didn't help either.

I was expecting to successfully build and run the Flutter project without any errors related to the "contacts_service" package. I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions to resolve this issue.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':contacts_service:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':contacts_service:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: /Users/meliharik/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar.
         > /Users/meliharik/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited
```

By the way, it's working on iOS simulator completely fine.

flutter doctor logs:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.7.11 on channel stable at /Users/meliharik/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f72efea43c (4 weeks ago), 2023-04-11 11:57:21 -0700
    • Engine revision 1a65d409c7
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/meliharik/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/meliharik/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64 • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```